# Is there an easy way to run IE8 on Win7 or Win8?

Tags: web, internet-explorer-8, virtual-machine

Is there an easy way to get a copy of IE8 for testing purposes? I am building a website where over 90% of the audience has IE8. I need to somehow get a copy of IE8 for testing but I only have Win7 and Win8 OS. Is there a way to get IE8 to work on one of those OSs? I've seen conflicting opinions on the web (some of it outdated) and would like to ask the awesome Stack community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have 2 different Internet explorer versions installed on the same windows box.

Have a look at that link:

**How to downgrade to IE 8 from IE 9 windows 7 64 bit**

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-to-downgrade-to-ie-8-from-ie-9-windows-7-64/3bc50db2-2974-4860-b4e2-5b0a0c4711d9

and that one also:

**Remove IE9 and reinstall IE8 on Windows 7**

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0d88ec6a-f109-4974-9f85-33510b043d53/remove-ie9-and-reinstall-ie8-on-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: I have IE10 on my Win7 machine. Can I downgrade to IE8 ?

Comment: I have tried the steps mentioned here http://techdows.com/2012/11/how-to-downgrade-from-ie10-to-ie9-or-ie8-windows-7.html on a VM and it seems to work.

Comment: That techdows link you posted worked great. Thanks! Answered!

Answer (score 2):

Open your IE and follow steps below :

1. Open "Tools" on the top bar.
2. Select "F12 Developer Tools"
3. Select "Browser mode"
4. Select "Internet Explorer 8

Now you can easily test your website for IE8